# How to send hyperlink in message body using javamail API in my app?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I need to send verification email to the user in my application and in that mail i want to send an url as a hyperlink, i am able to send email successfully but i am not getting how to send hyperlink in the body text.

My code where i am sending email to user :-

```
class SendEmailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

String emailid = "email="+user_email+"&hash="+randomcode;
String link = "http://www.google.com"+emailid;
String body = "Please verify your email address by clicking on this link "+link ;

 Mail m = new Mail("abc@gmail.com", "abc@123");

 public SendEmailAsyncTask() {
 if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    Log.v(SendEmailAsyncTask.class.getName(), "SendEmailAsyncTask()");
String[] toArr = {user_email};
m.setTo(toArr);
m.setFrom("abc@gmail.com");
m.setSubject(subject);
m.setBody(body);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();


}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.v(SendEmailAsyncTask.class.getName(), "doInBackground()");

    try {
        m.send();

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Email Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }, 1000 );



        return true;


    } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
        Log.e(SendEmailAsyncTask.class.getName(), "Bad account details");

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Incorrect account details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }, 1000 );


        e.printStackTrace();

        statusDialog.setMessage("Account Details are not correct");
        return false;
    } catch (MessagingException e) {

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Email sending failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }, 1000 );



        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
    super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

}
}
```

This one is my Mail.class :-

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String _user;
    private String _pass;

    private String[] _to;
    private String _from;

    private String _port;
    private String _sport;

    private String _host;

    private String _subject;
    private String _body;

    private boolean _auth;

    private boolean _debuggable;

    private Multipart _multipart;



    static {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
    }




    public Mail() {
        _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
        _port = "465"; // default smtp port
        _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

        _user = ""; // username
        _pass = ""; // password
        _from = ""; // email sent from
        _subject = ""; // email subject
        _body = ""; // email body

        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
    }

    public Mail(String user, String pass) {
        this();

        _user = user;
        _pass = pass;
    }

    public boolean send() throws Exception {
        Properties props = _setProperties();

        if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
            }
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            msg.setSubject(_subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // setup message body
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            msg.setContent(_multipart);

            // send email
            Transport.send(msg);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
    }

    private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

        if(_debuggable) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }

        if(_auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        return props;
    }

    // the getters and setters
    public String getBody() {
        return _body;
    }

    public void setBody(String _body) {
        this._body = _body;
    }

    public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this._to=toArr;
    }

    public void setFrom(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this._from=string;
    }

    public void setSubject(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this._subject=string;
    }

    // more of the getters and setters …..
}
```

Please guide me how to send text and hyperlink in the message body of the email which i am sending in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the official [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android).

Then, fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

To send a clickable link, send HTML email.  Set _body with a string that includes the html content you want in the message.  Change the code that sets the message body to:

```
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(_body, "utf-8", "html");
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had the problem of setting the body text
when I send electronic mail with the mailapi.
I was able to add attachments to my message in my program.

I did have trouble setting the body itself.
Here is what works for me==and I used `setText()` method as well.
(I have not tried it, but I assume one also could get the
`javax.activation.DataHandler` and then `getOutputStream()`
One's program couldthen put the correct body information in by writing on
that.

```
if (fileBody!=null) {
  javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart bopart = new javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart();
// accumulate the text of the file into a String AND put it as the content
// of this message
  FileReader FI;
  FI = new FileReader(fileBody);
  BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader (FI);
  StringBuffer B;
  B = new StringBuffer();
  String L;
  L = BR.readLine();

  while(L !=null){ 
    B.append(L);
    L = BR.readLine();
  }
  
  bopart.setText(B.toString());
  bopart.setDisposition(Part.INLINE);
  Debug.P("did setText on body |"+bopart+"|");
  parts.addBodyPart(bopart);
}
```